# Skipping an index while iterating a Map in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration, java-stream

Hi am looking forward for your help in skipping an index during an iteration of Map in java.
I have a map of 10 elements and i want to skip the element on index 8 how can i achieve the target.
I tried using skip() method of streams() but it is skipping elements from start to the count which you input. Following is my approach...

```
public void copyRow(Row row){
        this.clear();
        row.entrySet().stream().skip(8).forEach(e ->
        this.put(e.getKey(),new Cell(e.getValue().getRowNo(),e.getValue().getColNo(),e.getValue().getValue()))
        );
```

is there any way to do it in streams or is there any other way?

Comment: What type of map is it?

Comment: "map" and "index" are normally not compatible. Even a sorted map doesn't have an explicit notion of an index but rather all positional operations (head, tail etc.) are based on element comparison. So if you have a sorted map and know what element should be at "index" 8 (or 9) you could use `tailMap(element at 9)` (the passed element is included).

Comment: Btw, to me `Row` would indicate something more than just a simple map. If this is the case there's probably something better than an entry set to use, we'd just have to know what `Row` actually is.

Comment: One other thought: if the order that `entrySet()` provides is ok for you (depends on what map you have, note that unless it's a sorted map the order might not be deterministic) you could try a 2-step approach: first use `limit(7)` to get the first 7 elements then use `skip(8)` to get elements 9+. - _Disclaimer: please first read all the other comments and answers and try to pick a better suited approach. Use this only as a last resort._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash maps are not ordered so there is no concept of "index". No ones knows what the entry at index 8 is - might be different every time.

A much better idea is to check the key. If there isn't a fixed key associated with the value you want to skip, you probably should design how your data is stored. Because if that's true, then you are storing data based on the non-existent concept of "index", which doesn't work quite well.

To skip a particular key, just call `filter`:

```
row.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(someKeyThatIdentifiesTheEntryAtIndex8))
    .forEach(e ->
        this.put(e.getKey(),new Cell(e.getValue().getRowNo(),e.getValue().getColNo(),e.getValue().getValue()))
    );
```

If you are using a collection that has the concept of "index", like an array or list, you can do something like this:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

IntStream firstPart = Arrays.stream(a).limit(7);
IntStream secondPart = Arrays.stream(a).skip(8);
IntStream finalStream = IntStream.concat(firstPart, secondPart);
finalStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will try and will get back to you :)